# Case insensitive for loading XML file name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi all I am loading XML file with file name 'Attachments.xml' using the following code:

```
var attachmentsXml = XmlBuddy.load(file, 'Attachments.xml');
```

Now if I want to load the xml-file with file name as 'attachments.xml' I am unable to load so can anyone suggest me how to do.

Comment: What does "Unable to load" mean? An error? Please be more specific, also what is XmlBuddy? Some library? Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: @Esko I have an xml file with file name(Attachments.xml') and using the above code i can load that file now i have another xml file with file name 'attachments.xml' and if i try to load i get an error unable to locate attchment.xml as the name is different because it has small 'a'. so I want to make the file name case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using node.js so you can use the [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json)

```
fs = require('fs');
var parser = require('xml2json');

fs.readFile( './Attachments.xml', function(err, data) {
    var json = parser.toJson(data);
    console.log("to json ->", json);
 });
```